# Constructor is undefined?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity

Why I am getting this error `The constructor MyTabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager, List<Fragment>) is undefined`.

the code below contains the imports and how i instantiate the`MyTabsPagerAdapter` class. Despite that class exists, when i instantiate it, i receive the error mentioed above.

please let me know where is my mistake or what I am missing

**Code_with_imports**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.example.mqtt_test_00.adapter.MyTabsPagerAdapter;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MessaginActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
private ViewPager  mViewPager;
private MyTabsPagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
private ActionBar mActionBar;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.messagin_activity_layout);

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mActionBar = getActionBar();
    mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    List<Fragment> mFragList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
    mFragList.add(new Pub_Frag());
    mFragList.add(new Sub_Frag());

    mPagerAdapter = new MyTabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), mFragList);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
}
```

**class2MyTabsPagerAdapter**:

```
package com.example.mqtt_test_00.adapter;
import java.util.List;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class MyTabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

List<Fragment> mFragList;

public MyTabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> mFragList) {
    super(fm);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.mFragList = mFragList;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return this.mFragList.get(arg0);

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return this.mFragList.size();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Fragments in your List are not the same type. Look at your imports:

**MessaginActivity**

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

**MyTabsPagerAdapter**

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

Change your fragments in MessaginActivity to support fragments.

Comment: thany you. but afer doing as u suggested eclipse says change "add2 to "addAll" on this lines "List<Fragment> mFragList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
  mFragList.add(new Pub_Frag());
  mFragList.add(new Sub_Frag());"

Comment: Do your `Pub_Frag` and `Sub_Frag` classes extend the support Fragment too?